# Primefaces 6.1.1 Carousel slider movement issue

Tags: primefaces, carousel

We have migrated our project from primefaces 5.0.4. to 6.1.1, when we migrate primeface carousel component we have faced the slider moment issue which is sliding 4 by 4.

Earler verson the movemenet is working with 2 by 2. But current primefaces version is working with 4 by 4.

```
<p:carousel id="coro2" value="#{xlist}" var="p" itemStyleClass="carItem" numVisible="4" responsive="true" styleClass="carouselAdvanced span9">...</p:carousel>
```

Comment: What is 'sliding 4 by 4'? You have `numVisible="4"` so displays and 'pages' with 4 records each time... If that is not it, I have no clue what you mean

Comment: Oh and btw, it works with 6.1? Since you so explicitly used 6.1.1 in the title?